# Debian packaging: deploying files to the user home directory

Tags: debian, packaging, debian-based, software-packaging, debhelper

I use Debhelper to create Debian packages. To deploy files and directories, I use the `debian/install` and `debian/dirs` files.

Now I would like my package to deploy the default user configuration file to $HOME/.mypackagerc (just like .bashrc and friends).

Does Debhelper provide a way to do this, or should I just:

- Do it in postinst script
- Or even do this in my program, at first execution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should do it in your own program.

You can't get debhelper to do this. A postinst script may be able to install in all current user accounts, but you lose control of what happens after the user has performed the installation. So new users won't get the `~/.mypackagerc` files, unless you put it in `/etc/skel` also which is overdoing it, in my opinion.

I also say this because the package is installed by root. Root shouldn't have to mess around with other user's files. I don't know whether Debian Policy has anything on this, but you'll save yourself writing a lot of ugly code if you program made these files itself.

HTH

Comment: Okay, I'll do it in my own program, but have can I tell `aptitude` later to remove these files? I will not be able to handle this if I not change `install/postinst/etc` scripts accordingly.